# jQuery get text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function that returns some html like this:

```
return ("<span class='opt'>some text</span>");
```

I use it within the success callback function in $.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       $(tag).append(format(html));
    }
});
```

`html` give the `<span></span>` element. I want to retrieve just the text without the tags. I tried it using format(html).text() but it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do jQuery operations on a string of HTML, use jQuery to convert it first:

```
var newContent = $(format(html)); // use the results of `format(html)` to make a jQuery selection
$(tag).append(newContent.text()); // use the jQuery text method to get the text value of newContent
```

[See the API for an explanation of how this works](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2).

Answer (score 3):

`$('<span class="opt">some text</span>').text()` should do the job or in your case:

```
$(tag).append($(format(html)).text());
```

Comment: You're missing `()` after `text` there. You'll append a part of the jQuery source code with this!

Comment: Yeap, just realized and fixed that :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(tag).append($(format(html)).text());
```

That will take the text "`<span>...</span>`", convert it into a jQuery object, and extract the text, leaving behind the tags.