# Select text inside <b></b> tags

Tags: jquery

I think is a simple question, but I am having some issues with that.

I need to get the value between **`<b></b>`**
It is inside of a tbody, tr, and td.

Here is the HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tbody class="connectedSortable" id="table-draggable-@i">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <b>@year.Year</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery is the following:

```
$("#table-draggable-2 > tr:first > td > b")
```

And as a result I get:

```
[<b>​2017​</b>​]
```

But I just need the 2017 value. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705474/jquery-get-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Try this:

```
var value = $("#table-draggable-2 > tr:first > td > b").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get result of B tag:

```
$("#table-draggable-2 tr:first").find('b').text();
```